# Is there a way to use native features in Salesforce1?

Tags: salesforce1-app, geolocation

I wonder if the APIs are available, using which we can use phone hardware:

- Camera
- GPS
- Storage

This could help build some awesome application! I know this is not what Salesforce1 is built for. But still, has anyone done this?

Comment: Yes, you can. Refer the mobile SDK guide. https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-Shared/blob/master/doc/mobile_sdk.pdf?raw=true.....

Comment: Access Camera: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24650/use-salesforce1-mobile-app-to-access-camera

Comment: GPS: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/12/salesforce1-cures-the-app-boogie-fever.html

Comment: Storage: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2011/06/using-html5-offline-with-forcecom.html