# How can I access to the Android camera directly from Salesforce 1

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, android, bootstrap

I want to open the camera in an Android device from Saleforce1. I've seen many blogs that say that it is possible in android but always the screenshots are with an IOS device.

Salesforce1 can open the camera when you want to post a picture in chatter like this:

[image]

The take picture open the camera directly.

Now in my visualforce page I have a Button to open the camera with this code

```
<input id="picture_info" type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" capture="camera" onchange="" />
```

But when I click on it, I need to select an Image from my gallery:

[image]

[image]

I would like to open with a button the camera directly as the Salesforce1 "Take picture" button. Is something that I can do? it is possible?

I'm using a Google Nexus 5 device with Android 5.1, also I tested it with Android 4.4.4 KitKat.

Comment: This could be useful Please check. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24650/use-salesforce1-mobile-app-to-access-camera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok Guys, I just saw that now with the last version of Salesforce1 v 10.0, and Android 6.0 the option to use the camera is available. I tried this in the same project without any code change.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this link it will help you a lot but it is working only for Nexus5 and IPhone6 read this article if need some help

Link : http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/access-camera-and-audio-recorder-of-mobile-device-in-visualforce-and-upload-as-chatter-file/

Comment: Hi I commented on this blog before, and it seems is only working with apple products, probably now with lighting something can be builded.