# Can Salesforce1 access device camera?

Tags: salesforce1-app, access, barcode

Does the Salesforce1 App have the ability to access a device's camera to perform a scan in real time using zxing or some similar library?

I understand that there is a method to "read" a barcode using a static image. However this is not a desirable solution for me. Please see [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24650/use-salesforce1-mobile-app-to-access-camera) for further details on that.

I created a native Android app that uses zxing to capture barcode information and create a url with parameters, however I had to abort this because I was unable to get the url parameters to Salesforce1 using a deep link.

My requirement is to scan a barcode, store the information and auto populate a Visualforce page in Salesforce1 based on the information scanned. Within my native app I was able to successfully scan a barcode, construct a url with parameters and populate a Visualforce page on the actual Salesforce site (https:///apex/Barcode_Scanner_Page?item=b5xU000000085ot). But the deep link technique (salesforce1://sObject/001D000000Jwj9v/view
) was unable to pass parameters to a Visualforce page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not going to be able to use the camera in Salesforce1; it does not have the Camera permission on any devices, as far as I can tell. According to the [Window API documentation](http://documentation.auraframework.org/lockerApiTest/secureWindow.app?aura.mode=DEV), you should be able to use [getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) in Lightning Experience; you'll just need to write yourself a component that calls the appropriate methods. It's probably time for you to consider moving to Lightning Experience.

Comment: So once I use getUserMedia to get the camera data, I will need to use an existing library such as QuaggaJS to capture/decode the barcode?

Comment: @Reticentz Yes, that would be the idea. I'm not sure which libraries are supported by Locker Service though, so you might need to do some research.

Comment: FYI I don't think it's supported: [Salesforce1 should support getUserMedia API](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000E7FJQA0)