# How to access camera in Vf Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

How to access Camera option in Vf Page

My Apex Code is:

```
public class CameraAccess{
    public ContentVersion cont {get;set;}

    public CameraAccess() {
        cont = new ContentVersion();
    }      

    public PageReference saveFile()
    {
        //Here how i need to save this...
    }
 }
```

Comment: You can not access camera through Apex code, so no point sharing the apex code. [This thread](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24650/use-salesforce1-mobile-app-to-access-camera) will help.

Comment: How to Give Path on Client...

Answer (score 2):

In mobile devices, you can access camera by using `accept="image/*;capture=camera"` in `<apex:inputFile` element. Use `ContentVersion` object to store the file.

VF Page

```
<apex:page standardController="Document" extensions="CapturePhoto" standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false">
    <apex:form id="theForm">
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!savePhoto}" status="status"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection >
                <apex:inputFile value="{!cont.VersionData}" fileName="{!cont.Title}" accept="image/*;capture=camera"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class CapturePhoto {
    public ContentVersion cont {get;set;}
    public CapturePhoto(Apexpages.StandardController controller){
        cont = new ContentVersion();
    }
    public pageReference savePhoto(){
        try{
            cont.PathOnClient = cont.title;
            cont.Origin = 'H';
            insert cont;
            return new PageReference('/'+cont.id);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.debug('@@'+ ex.getMessage());
        } 
        return Apexpages.currentpage();          
    }
}
```